# Testing Spring Boot REST json result

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot

I have some problem with checking json result

UserControllerTest class

```
package com.serwis.controller;

import com.serwis.PraktykiApplication;
import com.serwis.model.User;
import com.serwis.repository.UserRepository;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.test.WebIntegrationTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup;



@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(PraktykiApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class UserControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    User user;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        user = new User("login1","password","email");
        userRepository.deleteAll();
        userRepository.save(user);

        this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new UserController()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void createUser() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user/findall/").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.login", is("login1")));
        System.out.println(userRepository.findAll());
    }



}
```

User class

```
package com.serwis.model;


import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="avatar")
    private byte[] avatar;


    public User(){}

    public User(String login, String password, String email) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", login='" + login + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", avatar=" + Arrays.toString(avatar) +
                '}';
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public byte[] getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(byte[] avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }


}
```

UserRepository class

```
package com.serwis.repository;

import com.serwis.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{
}
```

userController class

```
package com.serwis.controller;

import com.serwis.model.User;
import com.serwis.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

/**
 * Created by Jodanpotasu on 2016-07-24.
 */
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @RequestMapping("/user/create")
    @ResponseBody
    public String create(String email, String login, String password) {
        String userId = "";
        try {
            User user = new User(email, login, password);
            userRepository.save(user);
            userId = String.valueOf(user.getId());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "Error creating the user: " + ex.toString();
        }
        return "User succesfully created with id = " + userId;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user/findall/")
    @ResponseBody
    public Iterable<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user/delete")
    @ResponseBody
    public String delete(long id) {
        User deleted = userRepository.findOne(id);
        userRepository.delete(id);
        return "USER DELETED: " + deleted;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user/update")
    @ResponseBody
    public String update(long id, String login, String password, String email) {
        User beforeUpdate = userRepository.findOne(id);

        User afterUpdate = userRepository.findOne(id);
        afterUpdate.setLogin(login);
        afterUpdate.setEmail(email);
        afterUpdate.setPassword(password);
        return "BEFORE UPDATE: \n" + beforeUpdate + " <br> AFTER UPDATE: " + afterUpdate;
    }
}
```

it should be like

> [{"id":1,"login":"login1","password":"password","email":"email","avatar":null}]

But i still have error output

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and that is full output

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at com.serwis.controller.UserControllerTests.createUser(UserControllerTests.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:253)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.serwis.controller.UserController.findAll(UserController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    ... 43 more
```

Spring boot version: 1.3.6 is there another better way to test json?

Comment: Step through with a debugger to find out exactly what is throwing the NPE for more assistance.

Comment: could you include the full stacktrace? and test class..

Comment: looks like your UserRepository is not injected properly (line 37 NPE) please post your test class

Comment: forgive me i have no idea how could i forgot about include here test class. I edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(PraktykiApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class UserControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    User user;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    UserController userController;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        user = new User("login1","password","email");
        userRepository.deleteAll();
        userRepository.save(user);

        this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(userController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void createUser() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user/findall/").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].login", is("login1"))); 
        System.out.println(userRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

it seems that spring boot did not see

```
this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new UserController()).build();
```